# Issue in making a Pie Chart using django with fully dynamic data

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I have a Django backend that is sending this dict :

```
{'New': 1, 'Pending': 0, 'Done': 0}
```

I have to make a pie chart with this, So
I tried:

```
labels: ["{% for key, value in pie.items %}{{key}}{% endfor %}"]
```

and the output is "NewPendingDone" instead of New, Pending, Done

My Full code is :

```
var config = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: ["{% for key, value in pie.items %}{{value}}{% endfor %}"],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#dc3912', '#ff9900', '#3366cc'
      ],
      label: ''
    }], 
    labels: ["{% for key, value in pie.items %}{{key}}{% endfor %}"] <-- here
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: ''
        }

    }
}
};
```

Here's the ss of the current situation.
[Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcvWJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### To generate the list you could do:

```
labels: [{% for key, value in pie.items %}"{{key}}",{% endfor %}]
```

Output: `["Key1","Key2","Key3"]`

```
data: [{% for key, value in pie.items %}{{value}},{% endfor %}]
```

Output: `[1,0,0]`

You don't have a comma, and the string is encapsulating the entire for loop in your example.

This should work.

(Even though it looks a little weird in the html script tag)

Comment: Now Pie Chart gone invisible as this code is counted as error in js

Comment: Can you try again? Checking to see if it has to do with the comma. I'm pretty sure this is formatted correctly (`console.log()` the data to check), so the issue might be with your charts. @ProudWadhwa

Comment: I taken chart from Chart.js and the data comes properly and the format you have written is wrong in js.

Comment: What's the format? Try removing the string tags from the `"{{value}}"` -> `{{value}}`. My bad. @ProudWadhwa